# What is the next/correct step when Ingesting data to GeoMesa through geodocker?

Tags: docker, accumulo, geomesa

I have setup a Geodocker-accumulo-geomesa configuration by cloning https://github.com/geodocker/geodocker-accumulo-geomesa .

To add some sample data, many websites suggest adding GDELT data, as this does not require specific converters.

I use the following commands.

```
docker cp C:path\20170712.export.CSV geodockeraccumulogeomesa_accumulo-master_1:/tmp/20170712.export.CSV 

docker exec geodockeraccumulogeomesa_accumulo-master_1 geomesa ingest -c geomesa.gdelt -C gdelt -f gdelt -s gdelt -u root -p GisPwd /tmp/20170712.export.CSV
```

I get the following response: Using GEOMESA_HOME = /opt/geomesa/tools

Nothing happens after this. What does it mean? What is the correct or next step?

Answer (score 0):

That repo is not maintained any more. Try using this one, and following the README: https://github.com/geodocker/geodocker-geomesa

Comment: Now, I am trying to use this repo. However, after using 'docker-compose up', the system keeps giving the following message.

accumulo-monitor_1  | 2019-04-10 08:50:35,205 [monitor.Monitor] INFO : Failed to obtain problem reports
accumulo-monitor_1  | java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner$ScanTimedOutException
...
accumulo-monitor_1  |   ... 6 more

Comment: Latest issue is being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611731/accumulo-monitor-experiencing-a-java-runtimeexception-when-creating-geomesa-inst)