# Accumulo-monitor experiencing a Java RuntimeException when creating GeoMesa instance

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

In order to setup a local GeoMesa-Accumulo stack, I've cloned a git repository (https://github.com/geodocker/geodocker-geomesa).
Next, to create an instance, I executed the following commands.

```
$ cd geodocker-geomesa/geodocker-accumulo-geomesa/

$ docker-compose up
```

However, there seems to be a problem with the accumulo-monitor as I keep getting the following message.

```
accumulo-monitor_1  | java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner$ScanTimedOutException
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator.hasNext(ScannerIterator.java:164)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.server.problems.ProblemReports$3.hasNext(ProblemReports.java:260)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.server.problems.ProblemReports.summarize(ProblemReports.java:320)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.monitor.Monitor.fetchData(Monitor.java:395)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.monitor.Monitor$2.run(Monitor.java:555)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
accumulo-monitor_1  | Caused by: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner$ScanTimedOutException
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner.scan(ThriftScanner.java:252)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator$Reader.run(ScannerIterator.java:80)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator.hasNext(ScannerIterator.java:154)
accumulo-monitor_1  |   ... 6 more
```

What should I do to resolve this issue and to succesfully create a GeoMesa Accumulo instance?

Furthermore, what is the impact of this error? Could I ignore it? An accumulo-monitor instance has been created as it is listed when using

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
4da4fb183893        quay.io/geomesa/accumulo-geomesa:geomesa-2.2.0-accumulo-1.9.2   "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:9995->9995/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50095->50095/tcp   geodockeraccumulogeomesa_accumulo-monitor_1
8edbea5b4d96        quay.io/geomesa/accumulo-geomesa:geomesa-2.2.0-accumulo-1.9.2   "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                                                             geodockeraccumulogeomesa_accumulo-master_1
f0d4a29f278a        quay.io/geomesa/hdfs:geomesa-2.2.0-accumulo-1.9.2               "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                                                             geodockeraccumulogeomesa_hdfs-data_1
3786a6292a10        quay.io/geomesa/zookeeper:latest                                "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp         geodockeraccumulogeomesa_zookeeper_1
b30c99bfcf0a        quay.io/geomesa/hdfs:geomesa-2.2.0-accumulo-1.9.2               "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:50070->50070/tcp                           geodockeraccumulogeomesa_hdfs-name_1
6220fd54dabb        quay.io/geomesa/geoserver:geomesa-2.2.0-accumulo-1.9.2          "/opt/tomcat/bin/cat…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp                             geodockeraccumulogeomesa_geoserver_1
```

(Note that there is a difference in 'created' because I tried somethings to resolve the runTimeException.)

Comment: Can you view the monitor UI at host:9995?

Comment: If I try http://localhost:9995 then I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: do you have any port conflicts? You can see the ports being bound in the docker ps command